# Solve the equation: $\arcsin(2x^2 −1) + 2\arcsin x = -\pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I go about solving the equation below:

$\arcsin(2x^2 −1) + 2\arcsin x = -\pi/2$

After appyling sin to both sides I end up with:

$(2x^2-1)(\sqrt{1-x^2}^2 - x^2) + 2x \sqrt{1 -(2x^2-1)^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}= -1$

Comment: Have you tried applying $\sin$ to both sides?

Comment: I have and that only gives me the answers -1 and 0, however the answer is -1 <= x <= 0

Comment: I suggest you show what you have tried.

Comment: I end up with this equation: (2x^2-1)(sqrt(1-x^2)^2 - x^2) + 2x* sqrt(1 -(2x^2-1)^2)(sqrt(1-x^2)) = -1

Comment: Please, update your question with what you have tried. In the comments, especially without using MathJax, that equation is hard to read.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Actually it would be nice to see the steps. If there are mistakes I cannot see them from the result.

Comment: There are no mistakes, I have checked with WolframAlpha, I just don’t know how to solve the equation, and it gives the right answer, -1 <= x <= 0, as well as a false root x = 1.

Comment: Check my answer below about the 'false root'. Also Marc Mingoulis gave an explanation about that in one of the comments. I provided an alternative method in my answer, in case you know derivatives.

Comment: for $t$  in (-$\pi$  /2 , 0)  it is always $arcsin(sin(t$ $-$ $\pi$$/2)) =-t-$ $\pi$ $ /2$

Comment: Why this question is on hold?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

As $\arcsin(-y)=-\arcsin y$

$$\iff-2\arcsin x=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin(1-2x^2)=\arccos(1-2x^2)$$

Now $0\le\arccos(1-2x^2)\le\pi\implies0\le-2\arcsin x\le\pi\iff0\ge\arcsin x\ge-\dfrac\pi2$

Now let $\arcsin x=y\implies x=\sin y,0\le-2y\le\pi$

$$\arccos(1-2x^2)=\arccos(\cos2y)=\begin{cases}2y &\mbox{if }0\le2y\le\pi\\
-2y& \mbox{if } 0\le-2y\le\pi \end{cases}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I do know there is not an easier than yours for this one! +

Comment: I’m having a hard time following this sorry.

Comment: @KGunnar, Please pinpoint your confusion

Comment: @KGunnar, Hope your are aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 2):

A method using derivatives: put $f(x) := \arcsin (2x^2-1)+2\arcsin x$. Observe that $f$ is defined on $[-1,1]$, it is continuous and $f(0) = -\pi/2$. Let us compute its derivative:
\begin{align}
f'(x) & = \frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-(2x^2-1)^2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
& = \frac{2x}{\lvert x \rvert \sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=  
\begin{cases}
0, \text{ if } -1 < x < 0 \\
\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \text{ if } 0 < x < 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
So $f$ is constantly $-\pi/2$ on $[-1,0]$. For $x > 0$ its derivative is positive, so $f$ increases strictly and you do not get other solutions to your equation.

A remark on your method: if you decide to apply $\sin$ to both sides be aware that you are actually solving more than one equation, because $-1 = \sin \left(-\pi/2 + k\pi\right)$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So when you get the final solutions of $\sin(\arcsin(2x^2-1)+2\arcsin x)=-1$ you should check which ones are also solutions of, for example, $\arcsin (2x^2-1)+2\arcsin x = 3\pi/2$. You see, $x=1$ satisfies the latter equation, but not the former.

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward method is to apply $\sin$ on both sides, the sine addition theorem, and to use the identity $\cos(\arcsin(\alpha)) = \sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$. This yields the following equation:

$$
-x^2(2x^2-1)+(2x^2-1)(1-x^2)+2x\sqrt{[1-(2x^2-1)^2][1-x^2]} = -1
\;.
$$

Now, I just very quickly scribbled this on a piece of paper, so please double check it. After some term manipulations, I got $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$ as solutions.

Comment: 1 is not a solution, however 0 and -1 are. All the solutions are within the interval -1 <= x <= 0

Comment: The only non-equivalent operations I performed were sines and taking squares. This means that not all solutions of the modified equation are solutions to the original one, however, all solutions of the original one are contained in the set of solutions of the modified equation.

In the example, $x=1$ is a solution only modulo periodicity: Plugging $x=1$ into your equation yields $\arcsin(1)+2\arcsin(1) = 3\pi/2 \simeq -\pi/2$.